# Экспорт данных из запроса MSSQL в EXCEL с помощью Apache

Tags: java, sql-server, apache

Нужно из запросов mssql вытащить данные в excel документы, все действия происходят с java
Как это организовать ? Подскажите литературу по данной теме

P.S. вставить запрос в JTable и после чего делать экспорт с таблицы в excel НЕ УСТРАИВАЕТ!

Comment: если есть возможность работать на стороне СУБД, то может это пригодится - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588945/183842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте запросы в СУБД с помощью [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html), полученные результаты сохраняйте в Excel с помощью [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Здесь есть аналогичные вопросы с ответами:

- [Exporting Resultset from Java database to Excel using Apache Poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933868/exporting-resultset-from-java-database-to-excel-using-apache-poi)
- [exporting sql query result to a csv or excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563376/exporting-sql-query-result-to-a-csv-or-excel)
- [Writing a large
  resultset to an Excel file using POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274076/writing-a-large-resultset-to-an-excel-file-using-poi)