# C# + MSSQL Отображение большого количества строк в dgv или аналоге, экономя память

Tags: c#, sql, память, outofmemoryerror

Доброго времени суток коллеги. Задача не тривиальна, есть несколько таблиц баз данных. Есть процедура которая возвращает строки за определенную дату, в отчетах необходимо использовать выборку за месяц, а это порядка - 3,000,000 строчек. столбцов не много, 5 штук заведомо известных. 
Столкнулся с проблемой иррационального поедания памяти:
Используя DataTable + DataGridView = порядка 2 гб, съедает больше всего памяти.
Используя SqlReader + DataGridView.addrow = Меньше 2 гб, но все равно много.

При всем при этом, Ctrl + A съедает еще 2 гб памяти, и Ctrl + C еще 2 гб. 
(Необходимо для копирования и формирование отчетов в Excel)
Самое забавное, Excel спокойно съедает 3,000,000 строк таблицы и прекрасно себя чувствует.

Comment: а сразу [эксель формировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588996/183842) не вариант?

Comment: ещё как вариант [power query](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/24/5854/)

Comment: `DataTable` довольно сложная структура потому ничего удивительного, что идет большое потребление памяти. Нужно создать класс, содержащий 5 свойств нужного типа, которые будут соотв. столбцам в DGV. Извлекать данные из БД и формировать List<T>, который привязывать к DGV через `BindingSource`. Данные из БД запрашивать не сразу все, а постранично. Отчет для Excel формировать отдельным запросом к БД опираясь на Id выделенных строк в DGV.

Comment: @Anatol, Сразу не вариант ибо сама программа также используется для поиска конкретных строк, или выборок за более меньшие даты

Comment: имхо, лишняя работа, в то время как эту логику можно перенести на сервер (в запрос)

Comment: @Anatol, Процедура на вход принимает начальную дату, конечную дату и один параметр. На стороне клиента необходимо только отображение и экспорт в эксель, что по вашему еще можно перенести на сервер?

Comment: 1) о какой процедуре речь? 2) вы только что говорили, что на клиенте производите фильтрацию данных, вот я и предлагаю делать это на сервере 3) если отображение на клиенте нужно только чтобы сделать копипаст, то это явно лишнее звено

Comment: @Bulson, можете поделиться примером класса, который формирует List<T>?

Comment: @Anatol, 1) Хранимая процедура 2)Я нигде не говорил, что на стороне клиента производится фильтрация данных. В клиенте есть 3 поля: Начальная дата, Конечная дата, Параметр1, эти данные передаются как параметры и выполняется хранимая процедура, которая возвращает строки соответствующим этим входным данным. 3 Отображение на клиенте это первоначальный функционал, большая часть работы связано с тем чтобы посмотреть Параметр2 и 3 у строки с Параметром1. Экспорт в эксель опционален и очень необходим.

Comment: 1) тогда тем более не вижу препятствий формировать эксель минуя эти пляски с копипастом 2) тогда как понимать это -*сама программа также используется для поиска конкретных строк*? 3) вообще не понятно при чём тут это и в чём проблема портировать эти параметры сразу в файл

Comment: можете внятно объяснить почему формировать эксель сразу *не вариант* и зачем вам отображать эти данные на клиенте?

Comment: @Anatol 1.При экспорте данных в эксель через Interop или ClosedXML съедается памяти сопоставимо с DataTable (порядка +2гб на 3,000,000 строк). По этому я и пытаюсь решить проблему потребления памяти первоначально. 2. Описания алгоритма использования, а не функциональных особенностей, все сортировки происходят на стороне сервера. 3. Большинство пользователей используют клиент для поиска одной конкретной строки, экспорт в файл для них излишен

Comment: 1) вы не понимаете видимо о чём речь идёт. зачем беспокоиться о памяти, если нагрузка будет на сервере а проблемы с памятью вы решаете на клиенте? 2) ничего не понятно 3) вот это основание, но это подтверждает что у вас проблемы с логикой. зачем тащить 3 000 000 строк на клиент, если клиенту нужна 1? добавьте условий в запрос  и приносите ему одну

Comment: @Anatol У вас проблемы со зрением или вы просто не читаете что я пишу? Клиент которому необходима одна строка, указывает Параметр1, программа отправляет запрос на сервер, сервер выполняет Хранимую Процедуру, возвращает 1 единственную строку и программа ее отображает. Какие 3,000,000 строк ему должен вернуть сервер если под Параметр1 попадает всего одна? Вы знаете как хранимые процедуры работают?

Comment: Вместо тучи невнятных комментариев надо писать нормальные вопросы и не возмущаться, что ваши фантазии не все интерпретируют так же, как вы. К слову, до сих пор сохраняются внешние противоречия в ваших объяснениях, но желания разбираться в этом больше нет. Успехов

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать програму в x64 (если у вас не используются специфические 32-битные либы, а так же если среда позволяет - то получится). По дефолту студия может собирать 32, укажите явно платформу x64.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали в комментариях глубокоуважаемые коллеги ), в виду того, что вы хотите сформировать файл excel в конечном итоге, смысла в выводе такого колличества строк нет.

при сильном желании вы можете в интерфейсе реализовать работу с фильтром и постраничным выводом информации с *пейджером*. Таким образом, пользователю будет доступен образец данных, и при желании он сможет все просмотреть.

А конечный результат формировать на сервере, отправляя в метод генерации отчета финальный фильтр, который настроит пользователь

Comment: Придется и Вам ответить тоже самое, что и коллегам, формировать файл Excel это не конечная задача моей программы, большая часть пользователей используют ее для поиска строк с одним единственным Параметром, Параметр может повторятся => строк будет две и более, параметр может быть не полный (первый 7 символов) строк будет еще больше, так что экспорт в эксель это опция, а не первостепенная задача

Comment: тогда и я повторюсь: зачем визуализировать все за раз ? если вы можете выводить по частям, скажем по 100 первых элементов, в соответствии с фильтрами, параметрами и сортировками. и возможностью посмотреть следующую "пачку"